# Terminal lost header on latest update

Tags: pantheon-terminal

i've just updated elementary and now the terminal does not show the header.

Anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you modified your system in any way? Any non-standard software sources?

Comment: Yes I have some ppa's that are not standard... but I have had them for some time now. The only direct relation that I see is the update. Am I the only one reporting this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Yes I think you're the only one experiencing this. It looks like you found the cause :) Out of curiosity, did this somehow happen while the window was not occupying the entire screen?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I don't know how but the window-state in org.pantheon.terminal.saved-state was "full-screen" instead of "Normal".

I used dconf-editor to change it back to "Normal" and now the terminal show the header.